# Polish characters indesign CS3

Tags: fonts

I got a word document translated into Polish which I am supposed to put into an idesign file. The indesign file already exists in English and the font used is Corporate SBQ. When I copy paste the polish version from word, all the polish consontants with the diacritics give me a pink square- I suppose that means that indesign doesn't recognise them. I tried the glyphs window, but some of the characters are not there. I cannot copy paste from another document, I still get a pink square. Is there a specific font which works for Polish? Is there any other way to do this? I tried the spell check, but most of the words which have this pink block do not appear as misspelled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you Google "Polish fonts"? I get quite a few.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a font file that does not include glyphs for these characters. Not each font file includes all imaginable variants and symbols.

It's harsh but true: you should try and find a font that does have these characters, and use that instead. You can use the Glyphs palette (Alt+Shift+F11) to browse through your installed fonts and their characters.

The spell check doesn't catch on to the words, because the correct text information is still in your document, the selected font just doesn't display it correctly.